# Rails: Using debugger to change execution path of Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I'm running Rails v4.x and Ruby v2.3. I'd like to use a debugging tool (e.g., debugger) to dynamically test different execution paths in a Rails view. Specifically I'm trying to test the two paths of an if statement (ie., "if" block and "else" block) within a Rails view. Here is the code withing the View I'd like to test:

```
<% if @categories.any? %>
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <ul class="listing">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="well col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
          <li class="article-title">
            <%= link_to "#{category.name}", category_path(category) %>
            <li><small><%= pluralize(category.articles.count, "article") %></small></li>
          </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <div class="center">
      <p>There are no categories currently defined at this time</p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

To do this I'd like to be able to dynamically change the return value of the @categories.any? method so as to force the desired execution path. Is there a tool that I could use to do this? Can I do with "debugger"? Pry?. If so could you provide some simple instructions of how it could be done?

NOTE: @categories is an instant variable containing values from a data model (Category). I'd prefer not delete the contents of the Category table just to test the else part of the aforementioned code.

Regards,
Jet

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you will have to edit the file anyway, to add a debugger line, you can just as well add another variable, can't you?

```
<% if (@categories.any? && !@never_run) || @always_run %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm trying to understand generically if I can use the debugger to dynamically alter the path of execution for testing purposes (e.g., dynamically change a return value or variable to dynamically change the execution path).